build mediapipe on Windows , unsuccessful
I want to compile Medipipe to a C++ version of MediaPipe, but I'm having trouble with the following:
system: windows 10
mediapipe: 0.10.9
bazel： 5.3.2
opencv: 3.4.10
bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH="F:\install\anaconda3\python.exe" mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world
WARNING: Download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.19.0/node-v16.19.0-win-x64.zip failed: class java.io.IOException connect timed out
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'nodejs_windows_amd64':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/123/_bazel_123/rq4am43z/external/rules_nodejs/nodejs/repositories.bzl", line 371, column 19, in _nodejs_repo_impl
                _download_node(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/users/123/_bazel_123/rq4am43z/external/rules_nodejs/nodejs/repositories.bzl", line 187, column 40, in _download_node
                repository_ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.19.0/node-v16.19.0-win-x64.zip] to C:/users/123/_bazel_123/rq4am43z/external/nodejs_windows_amd64/bin/nodejs/temp14176022034400669713/node-v16.19.0-win-x64.zip: connect timed out
ERROR: G:/code/mediapipe-0.10.9/WORKSPACE:560:18: fetching node_repositories rule //external:nodejs_windows_amd64: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/123/_bazel_123/rq4am43z/external/rules_nodejs/nodejs/repositories.bzl", line 371, column 19, in _nodejs_repo_impl
                _download_node(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/users/123/_bazel_123/rq4am43z/external/rules_nodejs/nodejs/repositories.bzl", line 187, column 40, in _download_node
                repository_ctx.download_and_extract(
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.19.0/node-v16.19.0-win-x64.zip] to C:/users/123/_bazel_123/rq4am43z/external/nodejs_windows_amd64/bin/nodejs/temp14176022034400669713/node-v16.19.0-win-x64.zip: connect timed out
ERROR: G:/code/mediapipe-0.10.9/mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world/BUILD:19:10: error loading package 'mediapipe/framework': at G:/code/mediapipe-0.10.9/mediapipe/framework/port/build_config.bzl:11:6: Encountered error while reading extension file '@bazel/typescript/index.bzl': no such package '@npm//@bazel/typescript': no such package '@yarn//': no such package '@nodejs_windows_amd64//': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.19.0/node-v16.19.0-win-x64.zip] to C:/users/123/_bazel_123/rq4am43z/external/nodejs_windows_amd64/bin/nodejs/temp14176022034400669713/node-v16.19.0-win-x64.zip: connect timed out and referenced by '//mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world:hello_world'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world:hello_world' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 58.350s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (52 packages loaded, 182 targets configured)
    currently loading: mediapipe/calculators/core ... (2 packages)
    Fetching @npm; Restarting. 55s
    Fetching @yarn; Restarting. 55s

Actually, I can log in to this URL directly from the web page ，like this

"Connect(ion) timed out" is not a C++ issue.

@Botje    I can log in to this URL （ https://nodejs.org/dist/）directly from the web page ,so i think  its not Network issues， I don't know what the problem is

Random guess: are you behind a proxy? Because browsers tend to be auto-configured whereas commandline tools require explicit environment variables. Don't check with your browser, check with curl or wget.

yes ，its  proxy;   used the  bazel-6.5 ,  A different problem has arisen  ：INFO:
ERROR: The target you are compiling requires Visual C++ build tools.
Bazel couldn't find a valid Visual C++ build tools installation on your machine.
Visual C++ build tools seems to be installed at F:\install\vs2022\VC
But Bazel can't find the following tools:
cl.exe, link.exe, lib.exe, ml64.exe
for x64 target architecture                                              but  ，cl.exe  link.exe，lib.exe,ml64.exe   all  in the environment
